# Why proof about a rational on open interval (a,b) works...

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

For the case $0 < a < b$ which is what I'm interested in, there is a proof that there exists a rational number on the open interval which I've seen many times but I don't really understand it.

I accept it's valid as I've seen it from reliable sources but I don't "get it". A brief expository statement to help me see why it works, as it's not obvious to me, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you choose a numerator $n$ that is large enough that $1/n < b-a$. In that case, the distance between consecutive fractions like $\frac in, \frac{i+1}n$ is smaller than the width of the interval $(a, b)$. That means that at least one of those fractions must be inside the interval.

Comment: It doesn't work without Archimedes, does it?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe You do need the archimedean principle, yes.

Comment: Why is the Archimedean principle required?

Comment: @SumMathGuy To prove the existence of a large enough $n$, or rather a small enough $1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying that every real number has a sequence of rationals approaching it. For example, $\pi$ is approached by the following sequence:
$$3,3.1,3.14,3.141,\dots$$
In general, any real number can be approached by rationals by taking the first $n$ digits.

Let $M=\dfrac{a+b}2$, and let $M_n$ be a sequence of rationals approaching $M$. Since they approach it, they eventually get within a distance of $\epsilon$ of it for any $\epsilon$. Simply let $\epsilon$ be $b-M=M-a$.

Answer (score 0):

A possible intuition. Consider the decimal sequences of
$$
a = \ldots a_{-2} a_{-1}. a_1 a_2 \ldots\\
b = \ldots b_{-2} b_{-1}. b_1 b_2 \ldots\\
$$

Find the first place where they differ, say $b_k$. Then the number
$$
k = \ldots b_{-2} b_{-1}. b_1 b_2 \ldots b_k
$$
is rational and is in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Not necessarily. Let $a=0.01$, $b=0.1$. It's saved when you write $b$ as $0.0999\dots$, though.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger i did say *intuition* - this clearly needs more work... In all fairness, the OP did say *brief expository statement*

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger not sure it is saved, $0.0\bar{9} \not \in (0.01,0.1)$...

Comment: (Typo in your question: The $b$ in the last equation should be another variable, since you already used $b$.)

Comment: No, but $0.09$ is. The new number ends where the decimal places differ.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger cute. fixed the typo too. thanks for your help